# Vert.x's Verticle(s) JSON/YAML configuration (preferable per environment)

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x

Is there a "reasonable" way to configure `deployment options`, `instances`, `worker`, etc. in Vert.x?

I would like to be able to "get rid" of `DeploymentOptions` while deploying and have that in a JSON/YAML configuration file that somehow Vert.x understands ― preferably split by "environments", in the same way Spring Boot does.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
class MainVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {
  private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass.name)

  override fun start(future: Future<Void>) {
    val config = config().getJsonObject("verticle_instances")
    deploy(AuthVerticle::class.java, DeploymentOptions().setInstances(config.getInteger("auth_instances")))
    deploy(HttpServerVerticle::class.java, DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config().getJsonObject("http_server_verticle"))
        .setInstances(config.getInteger("http_server_instances")))
    deploy(DialPadVerticle::class.java, DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config().getJsonObject("phone_verticle"))
        .setWorker(true))
    logger.info("Module(s) and/or verticle(s) deployment...DONE")
    future.complete()
  }

  override fun stop(future: Future<Void>) {
    logger.debug("Undeploying verticle(s)...DONE")
    logger.info("Application stopped successfully. Enjoy the elevator music while we're offline...")
    future.complete()
  }

  private fun deploy(clazz: Class<out AbstractVerticle>, options: DeploymentOptions) {
    vertx.deployVerticle(clazz.name, options) { handler ->
      if (handler.succeeded()) {
        logger.debug("${clazz.simpleName} started successfully (deployment identifier: ${handler.result()})")
      } else {
        logger.error("${clazz.simpleName} deployment failed due to: ${handler.cause()}")
        //stop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...and `config.json`:

```
{
  "verticle_instances": {
    "auth_instances": 3,
    "http_server_instances": 6
  },
  "http_server_verticle": {
    "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 9080,
    "cert_path": "server-cert.pem",
    "key_path": "server-key.pem",
    "use_alpn": true,
    "use_ssl": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Vert.x Config Launcher](https://github.com/foreksorg/vertx-config-launcher), but still, I think this should be a "core" functionality.

In any case, `DeploymentOptions` accepts a `JsonObject`...and that's neat. The only caveat is to make sure the keys in the JSON configuration file (not including the ones inside the `config`, of course) are the same as the values the method `fromJson` (`DeploymentOptionsConverter`) is "expecting".

The "partial" solution would be to have a `config.json` like:

```
{
  "io.shido.core.verticle.AuthVerticle": { },
  "io.shido.core.verticle.DialPadVerticle": { },
  "io.shido.core.verticle.HttpServerVerticle": {
    "config": {
      "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9081,
      "certPath": "server-cert.pem",
      "keyPath": "server-key.pem",
      "useAlpn": true,
      "useSsl": true
    },
    "instances": 5
  }
}
```

...pretty similar to a sub-set of what `foreksorg/vertx-config-launcher` does ― since I'm only interested in the *config injection* part.

Eventually, the (initially posted) `deploy` method will look like:

```
private fun deploy(clazz: Class<out AbstractVerticle>) {
  vertx.deployVerticle(clazz.name, DeploymentOptions(config().getJsonObject(clazz.name) ?: JsonObject())) { handler ->
    if (handler.succeeded()) {
      logger.debug("${clazz.simpleName} started successfully (deployment identifier: ${handler.result()})")
    } else {
      logger.error("${clazz.simpleName} deployment failed due to: ${handler.cause()}")
      //stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation explaining how `DeploymentOptionsConverter` works? Neither the Java Doc for [DeploymentOptions](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/DeploymentOptions.html#fromJson-io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject-)
 nor [DeploymentOptionsConverter](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/DeploymentOptionsConverter.html) mention how the keys are mapped.

Comment: I didn't; I read the source code — Vert.x is open source. I don't think the "mapping" will be documented anyhow, so this is more like a convention you have to live with until there is something built-in in "core" or an official artifact from Vert.x.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, no. However, you could make some adjustments to your `config.json` and your `deploy(Class, DeploymentOptions)` method to achieve a similar result.

For `config.json`, if you change the name of each verticle to the qualified class name and have a `deployment_options` object for each verticle, you could then modify `deploy()` to load the options without having to specify them in your `start` method. In Vert.x, you can provide default configuration options, so you could do something like:

```
override fun start(future: Future<Void>) {
    deploy(AuthVerticle::class.java)
    deploy(HttpServerVerticle::class.java)
    deploy(DialPadVerticle::class.java)
    ...
}

private fun deploy(clazz: Class<out AbstractVerticle>) {
    val options = getDeploymentOptionsFromConfig(clazz)
    vertx.deployVerticle(clazz.name, options) { handler ->
        ...
    }
}

private fun getDeploymentOptionsFromConfig(clazz: Class<out AbstractVerticle>): DeploymentOptions {
    val config = config()
            .getJsonObject(clazz.name)
            .getJsonObject("deployment_options")

    return DeploymentOptions()
            .setInstances(config.getInteger("instances", 1))
            .setWorker(config.getBoolean("worker", false))
}
```

Comment: Yeah! That's cool, but I wouldn't like to write exactly that `getDeploymentOptionsFromConfig` since you have to write code for the keys you want to include, and that's already done in `DeploymentOptionsConverter.fromJson`. I'll be posting another solution in a few minutes.